# In Wordpress, how can I programmatically check if a person trying to post has required items (like featured image, tag, etc)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP and Wordpress, and I need to edit a repo where the 'Publish' button only is visible if the draft of the article has the following: a featured image, a tag, and a section. I understand that what I need to write may go in functions.php, but even then, I'm very unsure on PHP and Wordpress. How might I go about this? Or if I am to make a plugin, how would I reference it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check things, happening before the page reloads => javascript validation

If the user should be able to press the publish button:
use the hook "save_post" in functions.php there you can check everything in the $_POST variable. If something is missingyou can set the post to draft again with wp_update_post().

Anyways, i would suggest you to use javascript for what you want to do.

**Edit**
Use jQuery!
(go to your theme and use the theme.js if you got one | if you dont have a js. there create one and register it with wp_register_scripts in functions.php)
in that .js file you can disable the post-publish button with

```
jQuery('#idOfButton').disable();
```

Then you need to build the checks, which look if the needed post-data is set:

```
jQuery('#idOfNeededField, #idOfNeededField-2, #idOfNeededField-3').change(function(){
    let allowedToPublish = true;
    if (jQuery('#idOfNeededField').text().length = 0) {
        allowedToPublish = false;
    }
    if (jQuery('#idOfNeededField-2').text().length = 0) {
        allowedToPublish = false;
    }

    if (jQuery('#idOfNeededField-3').text().length = 0) {
        allowedToPublish = false;
    }

    if (allowedToPublish) {
        jQuery('#idOfButton').enable();
    }
}
```

**This code is not working its just a idea of concept! You need to edit it to your needs!**

If you´re checking  - Fields use .val() instead of .text()

Comment: where would the javascript injection actually go tho? I would rather the button be greyed out unless the conditions are met.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: which files does this go into? I'm looking at wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php but I'm not sure

Comment: I'm not in the wp-includes; I'm in wp-admin directory and *it's* /includes. I'm being tasked at work with jumping into this WP. Please help me.

Comment: so can I take that snippet, cut/paste it into my theme.js, which is inside my wp-admin/js/ folder, and paste that? obviously editing the id names

Comment: Yeah kind of. I dont know what fields you´re trying to check, but thats kind of the way how to do it. You will probably need to google a little bit to make this snippet working

Comment: I wanna check featured image, tag, and category.

Comment: do I need to wrap it in a `jQuery(document).ready(function($){}?